# My new sennheiser doesn't have an XLR port, what is this plug called? (picture included)

Tags: microphone, xlr

I'm new to the world of sound equipment, but I found a really nice deal on a used Sennheiser ME 66. Unfortunately, I was expecting an XLR port, but instead it has this (see picture). I'm not sure what to call that, so I have no cord to plug this microphone into anything. The plug is about 1.5 inches deep into the microphone. I'm a little worried I got ripped off, but that might just be a testament to how little I know about microphones.

So what is the name of this kind of plug? What kind of equipment do I need to use this microphone? Thanks in advance.

[image: Plug of a new Sennheiser ME 66]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a modular system.

You need the microphone module, which you have, and the power module, which you apparently don't have.

According to Sennheiser documentation you need the K6 or K6P power module.
http://en-us.sennheiser.com/directional-microphone-shotgun-film-broadcast-me-66